# How to find similar meaning words from list using WordNet in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, count, wordnet, senti-wordnet

I have a list of words like *teacher, professor, lecturer*. I want to find all such similar meaning words in my list and count them under a TEACHER category. And I have many such different categories. How can I find similar meaning words in python? Any idea? Before I was simply searching by words like:

```
def Make_cluster(title,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6):
try:
 
    print(title," ******")
    chartTitles.append(title)
    afinn= Afinn()
    count=0
    totalC=0
    rows= extract_data('swansea')

    for row in rows:

        if w1 in row[0] :
           totalC += 1
        elif w2 in row[0]:
           totalC += 1
        elif w3 in row[0]:
           totalC += 1
        elif w4 in row[0]:
            totalC += 1
        elif w5 in row[0]:
            totalC += 1
        elif w6 in row[0]:
            totalC += 1
   print("Total aspects",totalC)


Make_cluster('TEACHING', 'lecturer', 'course', 'library', 'teacher', 'study ', 'research')
```

But the problem is the above function only search for words given in function, and I can not pass all those words in a function, as some categories may have 5, some 10, some 20.
Is there any way to find all similar words from a list?

Comment: What is the connection to WordNet? (And could someone please flesh out or weed out tag [tag:senti-wordnet]?)

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop, and a list (or set). i.e.

```
count_words(data, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

and

```
def count_words(data, words):
    ...
    for w in words:
       ...
```